# Why is Xcode not recognizing argc?

Tags: c++, argc

I want to check if the caller has passed a value for `outOf`and if not then I want to use a default value.  I did some research online and saw that you can use `argc` to see how many variables are passed.  I tried using that in the below code but I got the following error

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'argc'
```

How can I fix the below code?

```
 #include "Mark.h"
 #include <iostream>


using namespace std;


void Mark::set(int displayMode){
    m_displayMode= displayMode;
}

void Mark:: set(double mark, int outOf){
    m_mark= mark;
    if ( int argc < 2){
        m_outOf=1;
    }else{
        m_outOf=outOf;
    }


}
void Mark:: Mark ::setEmpty(){
    m_displayMode= DSP_UNDEFINED;
    m_mark=-1;
    m_outOf = 100;

}

bool Mark:: isEmpty()const{
    bool result= true;
    if((m_displayMode==DSP_UNDEFINED) && (m_mark==-1) && (m_outOf==100)){
        result =true;
    }else{
         result = false;
    }
    return result;
}
```

main function

```
m2.setEmpty();
    cout << "Setting m2 to the raw value of m1..." << endl;
    m2.set(m1.rawValue());
    cout << "done!" << endl;
    cout << "m2: The mark is: ";
    m2.set(DSP_ASIS);
    m2.display() << endl;
    cout << "m2: With the raw value of: ";
    m2.set(DSP_RAW);
    m2.display() << endl;
    cout << "m2: And percentage value of: ";
    m2.set(DSP_PERCENT);
    m2.display() << endl;
```

Comment: Where is `argc` declared?  It isn't in the code shown.

Comment: I havent declared it. Should i declare it as an int

Comment: You have to declare a variable if you want to use it.  Adding one though probably isn't going to help.  Can you explain what you are trying to do? We can help you solve that.

Comment: When this function is called, if the
outOf argument is not provided, it will default its value to 1.

Comment: Thank you appreciate it!

Comment: When i googled it , it said to use argc. Not so familiar with that.

Comment: The `outOf` parameter has to be provided since it doesn't have a default value.

Comment: That is for command line arguments passed to your program at startup.  It won't help here.

Comment: Too much confusion here. Your method always need two parameters at call site! argc/argv is just to catch arguments passed from the command line. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

What you found is your research is that `argc` is used in `main` to determine how many command line arguments were passed to the program when it was called.  This is not what you need.

Since `set` takes two parameters, the caller will always have to specify `outOf`.  This means you never have to check if it was supplied.  If you want to be able to call `set` with or without providing `outOf` then what you need is a [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) for `outOf` that the code will use if the caller does not provide one.  That would change your `set` to

```
void Mark::set(double mark, int outOf = 1){
    m_mark= mark;
    m_outOf=outOf;
}
```

And now `m_outOf` will get set to `1` if you call set like `foo.set(1)` and will get set to the value of `N` if you call `set` like `foo.set(1, N);`

Answer (score 1):

There are two valid declarations for `main`:

```
int main()
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

If you want to look at command-line arguments you use the second one.